# Phonegap stuck at detecting iOS SDK environment

Tags: xcode, cordova

i'm trying to create my first app using Phone Gap, so i manage to Build a "generic" app, after installing node.js and phonegap.

So i'm trying to run the following command on the terminal:

```
phonegap build ios
```

And it always get stucked on **[phonegap] Detecting iOS SDk Environment.**

I have, xCode 5, and i do have all the profiles needed to develop, and distribute for iOS, in fact i couple of hours ago, i just send my first app to Itunes Connect, so i think my environment, is fine.

Any ideas? Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, instead of using the command **phonegap build ios**, I tried **phonegap run ios.** The program runs, and also a folder was created with the xCode files.

I still dont know what was wrong, but it worked for me.